# Make "The Comprehensive Formatting Test" into its own FAQ post

Tags: discussion, markdown, meta-faq

In the [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox) there is one excellent answer, [The Comprehensive Formatting Test](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/325826/361484). This answer gives examples of all known uses of markdown that are currently supported.

Whilst the answer isn't out of place in its current location I think it is far too valuable to be hidden in the Sandbox, and hence deserves its own FAQ post.

There is of course also an SE [help center article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) focused on formatting, but that is far less comprehensive.

Comment: Why not make a [tag:faq-proposed] post?

Comment: @EkadhSingh because there is already a post. I don't feel like duplicating content. We could have a mod/CM/dev  move the answer if the community feels that this is a good plan.

Comment: We can't move answers

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, that leaves 2 out of 3 options ;)

Answer (score 7):

Just some random thoughts, but the TL;DR is that I wouldn't mind turning this into its own FAQ post, but leaving it in the Sandbox too. Regardless of whether that means information might be in two places, and the answer to the Sandbox and the FAQ might eventually end up looking differently.

---

The answer is a good thing to have in the Sandbox itself: It shows the possibilities in the place where people might come to try/see what's possible. It's like a set of instructions, and removing the answer from the Sandbox to a FAQ post would mean that the Sandbox suddenly becomes a lot less educational. As such, there are a few different things that might be done to better show off this answer in its current position as well:

1. Use our votes to make great content float to the top and stay there.
2. Find out whether it's possible for SE employees to archive all answers in the sandbox, *except* that one.
3. Find out if that specific answer can be marked as accepted, and pinned to the top.

If any of those could be done, that's already a good first step to get the post a bit more visibility in the current Sandbox, instead of being drowned out by non-sensical unicorn images and waffles. Again, the answer is a good thing to have in the Sandbox itself, where people can refer back to it, edit it, try out things with it.

At the same time, the Sandbox seems pretty clearly not meant as a fully "serious' and "informational" place, and the informational value of this answer is so high it indeed seems better suited to have its own FAQ post, so the people that are *only* looking for information can find it without having to dig through other Sandbox answers.

---

As for giving the full answer its own FAQ post, I think that's a good idea. The FAQ has a section on editing and formatting where the information from this answer would fit in really well. I do want some preconditions though:

1. As soon as the faq-proposal post is made, protect it. Because the FAQ post should not be used as a Sandbox, and I want to avoid it getting a bunch of deleted answers doing exactly that.
2. Have the protected FAQ post link to the Sandbox, so people who want to try things out know where to go.
3. No trying to keep the FAQ answer from ending up looking different from the Sandbox answer. I want the FAQ post to be separate from the Sandbox, so edits don't have to be made in two places, and people can still freely play with the Sandbox while not having to worry about a 'precious' FAQ that might end up being a lot more static.
4. Split that one gigantic Sandbox post into sections: each section (like images/blockquotes/links) gets its own answer, and a link to that answer in the question. Like I said before, having information in a FAQ could be helpful to people that are *only* looking for information. An added benefit of separating the long answer into specific answers would allow quickly linking and finding specific information without having to dig through one big answer. It also would distinguish this FAQ from the one long Sandbox answer a bit more.

I think if that is done, the answer can be carefully copied over to its own faq-proposal.

Comment: Back when Shog was an employee, he'd routinely move Formatting Sandbox answers into a separate historically-locked archive question. If the team starts doing that again and the test answer gets moved, what would be your advice?

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Repost it, with a link to the archived original if needed.

Comment: It was never clear to me if the archive keeps all of the sandbox answers or just the latest archive. [The oldest answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47427/273494) on the current archive is nowhere near 12 years old. Are there other archives? We probably don’t need to keep it forever, but if it were in a more “documentation-like” place it could evolve as new features were supported.

Comment: @ColleenV I think there is just one Sandbox Archive, which also has A LOT of deleted answers... I see 1170 answers, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/3431/revisions) is the oldest, from July 8th, 2009 :)

Answer (score -5):

I say no to this for 3 reasons that I deem strong.

1. > There is of course also an SE help centre article focused on formatting

   But that can't be edited by the community. So it's less democratic and naturally more stale.
2. > I think it is far too valuable to be hidden in the Sandbox

   It's not exactly hidden, because it's on [the front page sorted by votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq). In fact, reason folks find the guide is probably because it's included in the sandbox which also has the noteworthy property of being frequently and liberally bumped.
3. > I think it is far too valuable to be hidden in (...) its own FAQ post.

   Absolutely. I mean, remitting such gem to the [FAQ tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?tab=Votes) tail would bury it pending numerous votes required to raise it back to due prominence.
4. > In the Formatting Sandbox there is one excellent answer

   I'd say having it thematically grouped reduces overall entropy.

Comment: This answer is really puzzling to me. Your opening bullet argues against the help center as an alternative, but the help center page isn't the proposed solution by the post above, it's more of an aside. Your 3rd bullet is a quote that's been twisted *completely* out of context to mean the exact opposite of what it means in the post. Finally, you introduce the post by saying you have "3 strong reasons" and then give *4*... These inconsistencies impact the persuasiveness and strength of your argument; disagreeing is *completely* fine, but you really should address OP's post on its actual merits.

Comment: @zcoop98 I did address the OP's post on its actual merits. The stylistic choices add necessary humor.

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but it didn't come across as humorous to me; it came across as odd and malformed, more akin to a weird typo that makes content harder to understand.

Comment: @zcoop98 the most demanding *aesthete* would consider this choice of form brilliant.